# configure deadletter queue for queue to lambda in amazon SAM yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to get a SAM YAML script properly setting up my lambda.  I have a lambda hooked to aqueue being created, which is just a simple

```
myQueue:
   Type: AWS::SQS:Queue

myLambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
     Events:
        myQueueEvent:
          Type: SQS
          Properties:
            Queue: !GetAtt myQueue.arn
```

(with a bunch of other properties taken out)... as far as I can tell it looks like I should be able to add a DeadLetterConfig and point it at another queue - but wherever I try to put it it doesn't work.

Essentially the behaviour I'm looking for is that if I put a value into a queue, then it automatically pops out of the queue into the lambda.  If the lambda errors in anyway (eg throws an exception) - the item ends up in the deadletter queue - otherwise it is consumed and disappears.    Am I just misunderstanding and this is just not possible out of the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out - you actually put it on the queue - eg:

```
  RedrivePolicy:
    deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt deadLetterQueue.Arn
    maxReceiveCount: 2
```